# sending single parameter through servlet

Tags: java, servlets

How do I send a single parameter through a query string in a servlet? The following code is giving me asyntax error:

```
out.println("\n<a href='delete?index=" + i  '">delete</a>");
```

Comment: you have missed `+"` after `i`.

Answer (score 0):

corrected:

```
  out.println("\n<a href='delete?index=" + i  +"'>delete</a>");
```